# What can I do if I submitted a paper believing a journal to be free for authors, and after acceptance I'm asked to pay a fee?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, fees, withdraw

Reading about a journal A, I understood that authors can submit papers free of charge to this journal. I have submitted a paper and received a letter of acceptence **with a bill**. The editor said that I have to pay print charges in order to publish my paper.

What should I do?

Can I withdraw my paper?

Comment: PhD students would normally have journal fees covered by their institution. I don't think there's any need to formally withdraw the paper - just notify the editor that you were unaware there was a charge and you're declining to pay.

Comment: The link does not say authors can submit papers free of charge. They actually are upfront about the $40/page http://www.pphmj.com/journals/jpfpta_author_information.htm

Comment: If that is the journal in question, it perhaps bears pointing out that this is not the reputable "Journal of Fixed Point Theory and Applications" published by Springer, but rather a deceptively named knock-off, the "JP Journal of Fixed Point Theory and Applications"

Comment: @Mark: which is a common ruse of predatory journals and surprise: the publisher, Pushpa Publishing House, is in the lists [Stop Predatory Journals](https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers/) and [Bealls' list](https://clinicallibrarian.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers/).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you may tell the editor that you were unaware of the author fees, and that since you can't pay it you are going to withdraw the paper. (They may agree to waive the fees, but if they don't, you certainly have the right to withdraw your paper and submit it elsewhere.)

In the future, you should check a journal's [own instructions to authors](http://pphmj.com/journals/jpfpta_author_information.htm) rather than (or in addition to) third-party sites, which don't always have complete or up-to-date information about the journal.

Answer (score 0):

There are some sneaky journals where you do not find out about the fee until after submission.  I wonder how often authors pay anyway, and how often they decline to pay.

Comment: Only fake journals use that kind of childish deception.